# Purpose of 'SDL_Rect' structure in SDL 2.0

Tags: c, struct, sdl

> ***Explanation :*** Recently , I have been trying to implement a game in C using SDL 2.0.When I dealt with rendering texture to the screen , I encountered a complicated structure named as `SDL_Rect`.

**There are also**;

```cpp
    SDL_Rect* src; // Source Rectangular

    SDL_Rect* dest; // Destination Rectangular
```

> **Question 1 :** What are the purposes of using these structures ?
>
> **Question 2 :** What are the differences between them ?

Comment: Can you please try to be more explicit about what's "incomprehensible" about a structure representing a rectangle? And a `SDL_Rect` can represent a specific rectangle on the screen, or in an off-screen buffer. And you can copy data from one buffer to another, which is probably what the "source" and "destination" rectangle variable are used for.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences between the src and the dest variable. These are just names of variables.

A SDL_Rect is just a good and easy way of storing the informations of a rectangle. The SDL_Rect struct contains x and y coordinates as well as a width and height. These can be accessed through x, y, w and h in the struct.

This can be used to store the dimensions and positions of rectangular textures.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of SDL_BlitSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface):

> The width and height in srcrect determine the size of the copied rectangle. Only the position is used in the dstrect (the width and height are ignored). Blits with negative dstrect coordinates will be clipped properly.
>
> If srcrect is NULL, the entire surface is copied. If dstrect is NULL, then the destination position (upper left corner) is (0, 0).

In other words, these parameters allow you to copy only a part of the rectangle and specify the destination position.

Comment: This isn't explaining what the `SDL_Rect` is!

Comment: That is obvious from the struct definition. OP's question was about what the two rects are *used for*.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one is the source, the other is the destination. But they're the same type.

Also, incomprehensible? (**EDIT**: now you say "complicated", but still) They're rectangles. It's an abstraction used in 2d graphics programming to represent a rectangular area on your screen (highly simplified definition!), which you can manipulate (e.g. move it on the screen, resize it...).

Comment: Sorry to use that phrase to describe the problem.I fix it.

Comment: No problem, it's just that it will influence the answers you get.